# VueJS2: Cannot read property even after v-if on parent element

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

So I am busy creating an app if you have logged in a user object will be filled with info.

The situation here is that i created a function **IsLoggedIn()** If I console.log it it returns false. Also it doesnt show the element where it's on(logic).

The function **IsLoggedIn()** is called on an element with the **v-if** attribute.

On one of the child elements i'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_type' of null"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src\pages\dashboard\main.vue
>          
>            
>               at src\App.vue

Code(shortened and got rid of some unnecessary code)

```
<div>
    <v-app id="inspire" v-if="isLoggedIn()">
       <v-navigation-drawer fixed v-model="drawer" app >
           <v-list dense v-show="user.user_type == 0">
              <!-- general section-->
              <v-subheader>Student</v-subheader>
                <v-list-tile :to="{name : 'Competitions-students'}" exact>
                   <v-list-tile-action>
                      <v-icon>fa-trophy</v-icon>
                   </v-list-tile-action>
                   <v-list-tile-content>
                      <v-list-tile-title>Open competitions</v-list-tile-title>
                   </v-list-tile-content>
               </v-list-tile>
               <!-- admin section-->
           </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
      <v-content>
          <router-view></router-view>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>

    <v-app v-if="!isLoggedIn()">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-app>
   </div>
```

So I for a fact know that isLoggedIn() returns false. And that the first v-app isnt shown but still the elemnt v-list with the v-show gives an error on user.user_type == 0

```
<v-list dense v-show="user.user_type == 0">
```

Comment: `user` is null, so: `user && user.user.type == 0`

Comment: @tom10271 same result. On top of that the IsLoggedIn function is 100% returning false even if i put false in there.

Comment: <v-menu offset-y> I think you have not close it

Comment: @tom10271 sorry mate my bad its closed in the complete code forgot to edit that in. Its a piece thats irrelevant for the code and it is closed in the real code im having.

Comment: Then I seriously don't have enough clue to tell what is the problem

Comment: @tom10271 its the craziest error I had even if i change the isloggedin() with false it still gives the error.

Comment: Why don't you show your scripts? it will help us to get a clue to know how your isLoggedIn method and data function looks like.

Comment: I can say that if you are not using vue dev tool (chrome extension) try once. it will help much

Comment: Can you change ` v-if="isLoggedIn()"` to  v-if="false" and remove `    <v-app v-if="!isLoggedIn()">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-app>`? If it works then thr bug is coming from the lower part not the upper part

Comment: @tom10271 appearantly so, which is pretty weird. THats something that shouldnt happen also this issues werent here in ap revious version

Comment: @tom10271 I fixed it by putting div's arround both v-app's and then  putting the v-if on the div

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
 <div v-if="isLoggedIn()">
    <v-app id="inspire">
       <v-navigation-drawer fixed v-model="drawer" app >
           <v-list dense v-show="user.user_type == 0">
              <!-- general section-->
              <v-subheader>Student</v-subheader>
                <v-list-tile :to="{name : 'Competitions-students'}" exact>
                   <v-list-tile-action>
                      <v-icon>fa-trophy</v-icon>
                   </v-list-tile-action>
                   <v-list-tile-content>
                      <v-list-tile-title>Open competitions</v-list-tile-title>
                   </v-list-tile-content>
               </v-list-tile>
               <!-- admin section-->
           </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
      <v-content>
          <router-view></router-view>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
 </div>
 <div v-if="!isLoggedIn()">
    <v-app>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-app>
 </div>
</div>
```

Appearantly calling v-if on the element itself will still render put a div arround both v-app's works properly now.